# Найти последовательность чисел в массиве

Tags: javascript

Есть массив из чисел `4,1,2,3,7,9` с последовательностью чисел `1,2,3`.

```js
let arr = [4,1,2,3,7,9];

let i, pos = 0, res = [];


for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(arr[i+1] - arr[i] == 1){    
    
    
    res.push(arr[i]);
  } 
}

console.log(res);
```

**Вопрос:** как найти и вывести последовательность чисел в массиве?

Comment: А что вы называете последовательностью?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [4, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9];

let res = [];
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] == 1) {
    if (!res.length)
      res.push(arr[i - 1]);
    res.push(arr[i]);
  } else if (res.length) {
    break;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```