# Найти все и любые (по возрастанию или по убыванию) последовательности в массиве

Tags: javascript

**Есть такой массив чисел:** `[4, 1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 70, 0, -1, -2, 20, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9]`.

**На выходе** должно получиться: `[1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, -1, -2, 5, 4, 3, 2]`.

Последовательность: разница между соседними числами в единицу.

```js
let arr = [4, 1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 70, 0, -1, -2, 20, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9];


let res = [];
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] == 1) {
    if (!res.length)
      res.push(arr[i - 1]);
    res.push(arr[i]);
  } else if (res.length) {
    continue;
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

**Вопрос:** как найти все последовательности (числа с разностью в единицу) по возрастанию?

В продолжение [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1271132/212421).

Comment: Почему не попадает 7,6?

Comment: @AzizUmarov, и 7,6 попустила

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [4, 1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, -1, -2, 20, 5, 4, 3, 2, 9];
let expected = [1, 2, 3, 7, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12, 0, -1, -2, 5, 4, 3, 2];

let r = [];
let res = [];
let d = 0;
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  let di = arr[i] - arr[i - 1];

  if (Math.abs(di) != 1) {
    r.push(res);
    res = [];
    continue;
  }
  
  if (di != d) {
    r.push(res);
    res = [];
  }
  d = di;

  if (!res.length)
    res.push(arr[i - 1]);
  res.push(arr[i]);
}
r.push(res);
r = r.flat();
console.log(JSON.stringify(r), "result");
console.log(JSON.stringify(expected), "expected");
```

Comment: И тут же ответ от Игоря